Translations not working for shopify app block schema settings section
I've defined my app block schema settings and implemented the locales for them but this isn't working properly. Like the content from the default en.default.schema.json is loading but not working for other languages.
Here's my implementation:
Schema Section:
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "myApp - App Block",
  "stylesheet": "myAppsStorefront.css",
  "javascript": "myAppsStorefront.js",
  "tag": "section",
  "settings": [
    { 
      "type": "text", 
      "id": "MP_heading_content_middle_section_Text", 
      "label": "Steps Title Content", 
      "default": "t:section.schemaTranslations.selectTypeOfProductName" 
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}

The locales:
en.default.schema.json
{
  "section": {
    "schemaTranslations": {
      "selectTypeOfProductName": "Select a type of {selectedProductTitle}",
    }
  }
}

zh-CN.schema.json
{
  "section": {
    "schemaTranslations": {
      "selectTypeOfProductName": "选择一种 {selectedProductTitle} 类型",
    }
  }
}

Here's the doc I followed. I can't seem to figure out what wrong.
